# Android Studio doesn't recognize WebView

Tags: android, android-studio, android-webview

I'm trying to build a webview and Android Studio is showing the messages below. Do you know how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Please do not post code inside screen-shots. Instead just paste the code as text and format it as code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have written java code in a kotlin file. In kotlin, you have to assign a value like this.

```
val webView: WebView = findViewById(R.id.webView).
```

If you want to write your code in java you have to select Java Class instead of Kotlin class/file while creating a new class or file. or in your case make sure to select Language Java while creating your project.